# A question about the $\ker$ of a particular group homomorphism, where the groups are both the non-zero complex numbers with multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

The following statement is paraphrased from *Linear Algebra: A Pure Mathematical Approach* by Harvey E. Rose on page 2-3.

If $G$ is a group of the non-zero complex numbers with multiplication, and $G=H$
then $\theta: G \to H$ given by $c\theta=c/|c|$, where $c\in\mathbb{C}$, and  $|\cdot|$  denotes the usual absolute value function, then $\theta$  is a homomorphism and $\ker \theta$ equals the set of complex numbers with absolute value 1; the reader should verify this.

**My Reasoning:**

The neutral element in $G$  and $H$ should be $1+i0$ right? Because $1+0i\neq 0$  and $1+0i$ is the multiplicative identity of $\mathbb{C}$.  So, $\ker\theta=\{g\in G : g\theta= 1\}$ right?

So, I tried to verify $\ker\theta$ by letting  $\xi=0.25+i\sqrt{1-0.25^2}$, then $|\xi|=1$ but $\xi/|\xi|\neq 1+i0$. Thus $\ker \theta$ is not the set of complex numbers with absolute value 1. I think $\ker\theta =\{1\}$ but I am not sure, is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say that the $\textbf{image}$ of $\theta$ is the set of complex numbers with modulus one?

Comment: @JamesCameron  I am sure. I wrote the statement word for word after $\theta:G \to H$, that information was on a previous page.

Comment: Well then you have proved that this is not the case, by exhibiting a complex number of modulus one that doesn't get sent to the identity under $\theta$!

Comment: @JamesCameron Thanks! But now I am a little worried about the accuracy of this book, that was only on the third page!

Comment: Something else the author could mean is that the only elements fixed by $\theta$ are complex numbers with modulus one, that would be true too.

Comment: @JamesCameron Yeah, he may have meant to say that, but he didn't write that. I don't feel like reading a book full of ambiguity. I will check out the books that you suggested below.

Comment: Although in the authors defense I read the appendix first, and it was pretty clear. And it covers in 75 pages what a similar book covers in 150 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the kernel is just $1$. Geometrically, this map squeezes the punctured complex plane onto the unit circle (it doesn't change the argument of a complex number, so it sends $re^{i\theta}$ to $e^{i \theta}$).  If you think of it this way and draw a few pictures it is clear that the $\textbf{image}$ is the set of complex numbers with modulus once because this is exactly the unit circle. If you've studied some topology you might recognize this as a retract of $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ on to $S^1$.

Comment: Thanks! I am actually taking analysis right now, and I am reading this book because I want a more complete treatment on vector spaces. Do you know another book that would give a thorough treatment on vector spaces? I would like to consider more abstract vector space then space in $\mathbb{R}^n$, would you have a good suggestion?

Comment: If this is your first or second time learning about vector spaces, one good choice is Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right. If you are a bit more experienced, Hoffman and Kunze is the gold standard.

Comment: Thanks I will check these out.